# error when serializing a BsonDocument using System.Text.Json in .net 6.0

Tags: .net-6.0, mongodb-.net-driver, json-serialization, bsondocument

I have a c# class as following:

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument ProductMetadata { get; set; }
}
```

The BsonDocument is coming from the MongoDB.Driver

My api code is as following:

```
// GET: api/<ProductController>
[HttpGet]
public Product Get()
{
    Product prod = new Product();
    prod.ProductName = "Test";
    prod.ProductCount = 20;
    var doc = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "metadata1", "val1" }
    };
    prod.ProductMetadata = doc;
    return prod;
}
```

When I call the Get api, I have the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo<T>.GetMemberAndWriteJson(object obj, ref WriteStack state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter<T>.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<T>.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ref T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo<T>.GetMemberAndWriteJson(object obj, ref WriteStack state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter<T>.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref WriteStack state)
....
```

It looks like the serializer is trying to cast the metadata1 to boolean! I don't know why...
any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: I think you missed providing some configuration. I doubt what you posted can generate this error. I would suggest create a simple repro in a different solution and check there

Comment: This example is from a small project that I created especially to post my question! I created a web api project, added MongoDB.Driver from nuget.org, added the Product class and the ProductController, that's all!

Comment: I pushed my project to github, you can check here: https://github.com/simoha76/TestBsonDocument

Comment: interesting, looks like a bug to me here `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`.

Comment: Maybe! but I wonder how the others are doing stuff like this... it's  a basic serialization!

Comment: I vote that returning BsonDocument from a Get method is ***not*** too common behavior. It will work if instead, you will convert BsonDocument to json on your side before returning it to the client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253939/discussion-between-dododo-and-simoha).

Comment: This what I did to solve that, converting it to json before sending the response...

Answer (score 0):

A custom json converter worked for me:

```cs
public class BsonJsonConverter : JsonConverter<BsonDocument>
{
    public override BsonDocument? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return BsonDocument.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BsonDocument value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToJson());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
public class Example
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(BsonJsonConverter))]
    public BsonDocument Data { get; set; }
}
```